# Поочередное нажатие кнопок

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать поочередное нажатие кнопок через таймер?

Comment: Что подразумевается под кнопкой? Кнопка клавиатуры или кнопка в программе?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov,  button в программе, что бы  button.PerformClick(); по очереди срабатывал, у меня звуки на кнопках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дизайнере добавляем в форму контрол `Timer` с именем `tmrButtonMash`

Устанавливаем свойство `Interval` таймера `tmrButtonMash` в 1000 (1 секунда).

Добавляем поле для хранения номера последней нажатой кнопки, предполагаем, что кнопок всего две, соответственно, значения 1 или 2

```
private int buttonClickedLast = 2;
```

Подписываемся на событие срабатывания таймера

```
private void tmrButtonMash_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Логика может быть заменена на более сложную и красивую
    if (buttonClickedLast == 2)
    {
        btnToClick1.PerformClick();
        buttonClickedLast = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        btnToClick2.PerformClick();
        buttonClickedLast = 2;
    }
}
```

Предположим, мы запускаем и останавливаем таймер по нажатию кнопки (можно также запускать и, скажем, в событии показа формы `MainForm_Shown`)

```
private void btnStartAutoButtonClicking_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!tmrButtonMash.Enabled)
        tmrButtonMash.Start();
}

private void btnStopAutoButtonClicking_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tmrButtonMash.Enabled)
        tmrButtonMash.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли

Answer (score 3):

Можно так

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   button.PerformClick();
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   button2.PerformClick();
}
```

можно так

```
private static void RaiseClick(Button b)
{
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   b.PerformClick();
}
```

и вызывать

```
foreach(var button in buttonCollection)
{
  RaiseClick(button);
}
```

для запуска в отдельном потоке

```
 Task task = new Task(()=> RaiseClick(button));
 task.Start();
```

Comment: пользователь не сможет же никуда наживать пока не кончится слип, поэтому я через таймер пытаюсь

Comment: @Valentin можно запускать в отдельном потоке, чтобы не блокировать основной, добавил в конце ответа